# Django - how to store different parsing techniques for different XML formats?

Tags: python, django

Every user has different `csv/xml` feed url. Some users feeds are "standardized" so the parsing techniques/scripts can be shared.  But some users has very unique feed formats and I need to write custom script.

I'm trying to figure out way to store such scripts so either I choose existing parsing technique inside admin or I write code and assign it to the object.

How would you do that?

My idea is to have a folder with these scripts and every object would have `FilePathField` so I can choose or create a new script. Is there another way?

```
class Feed(BaseTimeStampedModel):
    url ....
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    template = models.FilePathField(path='feeds/parsers/', recursive=True, match='tparser__.*')
```